# SalesforceIQ: Any way to undelete a list?

Tags: salesforceiq

I just deleted the wrong list on SalesforceIQ.  Is there *any* way to undo this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it located here? https://na14.salesforce.com/search/UndeletePage

Comment: @EricSSH That's for Salesforce though.  I'm looking to do this in SalesforceIQ

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there's no way to undelete or restore a deleted list. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.salesforceiq.com/articles/create-rename-delete-lists) as well.

> To delete the List: Click Delete List. On the confirmation screen,
>   enter DELETE THIS LIST and click Delete List.
>
> Note: Comments, notes, and manually logged events are all stored at
>   the List level and are permanently deleted when you delete a List.

One of the workarounds to restore it is if you've a CSV export, you can re-import it as shown here

[image]

Comment: Does it make a difference if I just deleted all the entries in the list and not the list itself?

Comment: I don't think this answer actually addresses the OP, albeit due to poor wording. The question seems to be about deleting records, not a `ListView`.

Comment: Perhaps the submitter can re-confirm. I answered it based on my understanding of the question based on the provided wording. Thanks!

Comment: @GauravKheterpal Sorry, Adrian Larson is correct.  I deleted all of the records in the List (the ListItems)